# How to recover OS and files after mistakenly executing "apt-get remove" on many libraries and Ubuntu won't open?

Tags: package-management, data-recovery

I mistakenly executed the following command to remove multiple packages and now I am unable to open Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian-all libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
```

Even the terminal and Ubuntu Software Center got deleted.

How can I retrieve my device files? What do I do now?

Comment: Did you try re-installing using Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then using "install" instead of "remove" in your command?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with `grub2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then logging in, and running

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

From <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, try running `startx` to get to your desktop. Also, try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, or the same thing for `lightdm`. If it still doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install gdm`.

Comment: No i dint :( i dint knw wt to do so i gave shut down and nw i cant open my ubuntu :(

Comment: Immediately i tried opening in recovery mode and it stopped in checking battery status....[OK] and so I dint know what to do so I powered off the system directly and now if I open ubuntu generic It got stuck and its display the same checkin battery status..[OK] in an unalligned manner and I cudnt go into login page.

Comment: I tried CTRL+ALT+F1 and installed the packages for which i gave remove.Thank u soo much it got installed. Then i gave "ls" command and all my files which i had saved before were listed.But Now am not able to open UBUNTU and use the user interface i.e am not able to login using Ubuntu generic.. Please help me :(

Comment: From CTRL+ALT+F1, try running `startx` to get to your desktop. Also, try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, or the same thing for lightdm. If it still doesnt work, try `sudo apt-get install gdm`